# Same prototype cell with multiple UITableView(s)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit

In Storyboard I can define one (or more) prototype cell(s) to be used with a `UITableView`.

However I'd need to use the same prototype cell with multiple UITableView(s)?

Is it possible?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to share a cell across `UITableView`'s is to define them in an .xib as a separate file and give them a reuse identifier. Then in code register that file / corresponding class to the `UITableView`.

e.g. place this inside the `viewDidLoad()` of your tableViewController:

```
tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle()), forCellReuseIdentifier: "")
```

And then you can continue on as normal inside the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: Thank you, please just note that there is a missing parameter into the `UINib` initializer

Comment: @appzYourLife you are correct, thanks. Typed that from memory without Xcode, forgot about it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a nib file (.xib), you can do that by doing **File** -> **New** -> **View** (under UserInterface section)

[image]

then setup your UITableViewCell element and set some reuseIdentifier, you can also create subclass if you need

then in your viewController (where you wanted to use this custom tableViewCell)

in viewDidLoad you need to register that nib with the tableView like,

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    // the .xib filename
    tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "CustomCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "CustomCellId")

}
```

then in cellForRowAtIndexPath, you can use it normally like the prototype cell,

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CustomCellId", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! Customcell

    // your custom code
    return cell
}
```